# Battery detected but not charging (remains 0%)

Tags: linux, power-supply, linux-mint, battery, netbook

I've recently bought a new, 6600 mAh battery for my Acer Aspire One Netbook (AOA110, ZG5 Model) and it refuses to charge.

My adapter will charge the old battery (although it only lasts 10 minutes), so the adapter is not at fault, and the battery is recognized.

If I run: `cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT1/info` I get the following output:

```
present:                 yes
design capacity:         6600 mAh
last full capacity:      6809 mAh
battery technology:      rechargeable
design voltage:          11100 mV
design capacity warning: 300 mAh
design capacity low:     272 mAh
cycle count:          0
capacity granularity 1:  32 mAh
capacity granularity 2:  32 mAh
model number:            UM08A71
serial number:           1444
battery type:            LION
OEM info:                SIMPLO
```

And this for the state:

```
present:                 yes
capacity state:          ok
charging state:          charged
present rate:            0 mA
remaining capacity:      0 mAh
present voltage:         4286 mV
```

I have updated to the latest BIOS version via Acers website after some searching of the web for solutions but this has not helped.

I am using an older netbook version of Linux Mint I think, Linux Mint 13 Maya.

Not being an expert on Linux, but being somewhat comfortable with it I was hoping to use this netbook more after getting this high capacity battery. Any suggestions on possible solutions would be appreciated, I am not adversed to reinstalling a different version of Linux on the netbook although obviously I'd rather not.

**Edit:**

I installed the latest Fedora onto the netbook but that did not help.
I greped some more system information comparing my old battery to new one, it looks like the voltage being received/given to the new battery is wrong:

```
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/alarm:0
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/capacity:0
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_full:6809000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_full_design:6600000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_now:0
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/current_now:0
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/cycle_count:0
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/manufacturer:SIMPLO
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/model_name:UM08A71
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/present:1
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/serial_number:1444
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status:Unknown
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/technology:Li-ion
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/type:Battery
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=BAT1
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Unknown
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT=1
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_TECHNOLOGY=Li-ion
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_CYCLE_COUNT=0
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN=11100000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW=4291000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_CURRENT_NOW=0
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL_DESIGN=6600000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL=6809000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_NOW=0
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY=0
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_MODEL_NAME=UM08A71
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_MANUFACTURER=SIMPLO
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/uevent:POWER_SUPPLY_SERIAL_NUMBER=1444
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/voltage_min_design:11100000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/voltage_now:4291000
```

I noticed that voltage_now is less than voltage_min_design with the new battery but the older battery listed them as:

```
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/voltage_min_design:10800000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/voltage_now:12029000
```

Comment: Is the battery itself charged? I.E. what happens when you unplug the cord?

Comment: I don't think it is as the netbook shuts off. I did some reading and apparently Acers BIOS doesn't always tell linux the correct battery type.

Comment: Sounds like your OS isn't calibrated for your new battery.  Were you running Windows, I could tell you how to reinstall the ACPI-Compliant Control Method drivers to recalibrate the battery.  Unfortunately, I've got no idea how to do this in a Linux environment, aside from a complete reinstall.

Comment: Thanks for the help nonetheless. I don't think this netbook has ever run windows on it sadly. I'll wait to see if anyone else has suggestions and then get a refund if it's just not possible.

Comment: I've flashed a new BIOS onto the Netbook, with no effect. So am trying a new install of a newer Linux distribution now.

Comment: The Amazon seller I bought it from is sending me a replacement, so I shall see if it was just a bad battery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the battery itself was defective, but I did learn a lot about flashing the bios and troubleshooting battery problems. See comments on the question for details.